# Can the magnetic field of the earth be utilized in a manmade craft?

Tags: electromagnetism

What if there was a magnetic ring around the craft on a gimbal that could freely rotate from positive to negative, then could the craft utilize the magnetic field of the earth without flipping the craft? The actual craft could be in the center as long as the ring was long enough to rotate around the center compartment.?

Comment: One could utilize the gradient of the magnetic field, but that's extremely weak (even weaker than the field itself), so in practice it's of no use. The magnetic field of Earth is being used by near earth orbit spacecraft to orient themselves. The technology is called a "torque rod" or "magnetorquer": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorquer and it's basically just a long electromagnet. Spacecraft that have to perform active attitude control usually use reaction wheels, as the torque from a torque rod is very small.

Answer (score 1):

In short the answer is theoretically yes,practically no. You should refer to newton's bullet diagram,which explains about the necessity for a certain velocity to keep rotating in earth's orbit and today spacecrafts use it for revolving around earth at an altitude where air resistance is almost zero and that 'weak force' is enough to drive the satellite around the earth. You are probably imaging a magnetic path around the earth which absolutely is but is too weak to be of any significant use,plus high air resistance makes the idea worthless, but it is theoretically possible.